# Is the expansion of this expression correct?

Tags: discrete-signals, convolution

\begin{align*}
&(\delta[n]+\delta[n-1])*(\delta[n]+\delta[n-1])\\ \\
=\;&\delta[n]*\delta[n]+2(\delta[n]*\delta[n-1])+\delta[n-1]*\delta[n-1]\\ \\
=\;&(\delta[n]+2(\delta[n]*\delta[n-1])+\delta[n-1])
\end{align*}

I am not sure if its true that $\delta[n]*\delta[n]=\delta[n]$ and $\delta[n-1]*\delta[n-1]=\delta[n-1]$ for discrete signals but I proceeded with this assumption. Furthermore, how do we compute the convolution $\delta[n]*\delta[n-1]$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convolution in time domain means product in frequency domain. DTFT of $\delta[n]$ is just $1$, therefore any arbitrary $x[n]$ when convolved with $\delta[n]$ remains same, as in frequency domain you are just multiplying $X(e^{j\omega})$ with $1$.

So, $Y(e^{j\omega}) = 1 \ . \ X(e^{j\omega}) = X(e^{j\omega})$. Hence, $y[n] = x[n]$.

Now, apply same principle for $\delta[n-1]*\delta[n-1]$ to see that the result will be $\delta[n-2]$.

Comment: Hello, is there a method that doesn't involve Fourier because I have not reached this concept yet :(

Comment: @deerclaysup Another way is to understand that convolution with $\delta[n-1]$ will bring 1 sample of delay to any arbitrary sequence $x[n]$. So, when $x[n] = \delta[n]$ gets convolved with $\delta[n-1]$, then it gets delayed by 1 sample and we get $y[n] = x[n-1] = \delta[n-1]$. And when $x[n] = \delta[n-1]$ gets convolved with $\delta[n-1]$, then it gets delayed by 1 sample and you get $y[n] = x[n-1] = \delta[n-2]$.

Comment: This makes sense now, thank you very much!

Comment: @deerclaysup No, you won't get $\delta[n]*\delta[n-1] = 2\delta[n-1]$, but you will get $\delta[n-1]$. $\delta[n]$ is your input signal and you are convolving it with $\delta[n-1]$, so the result is 1 sample delay in your input signal that is $\delta[n-1]$.

Comment: Yep you are right, I meant to my original expression it had the term $2(\delta[n]*\delta[n-1])$. Thank you once more :)